# Hiding browser MenuBar on pageload using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I have a strange requirement from client, he wants to hide the browser menubar on pageLoad.
Is it possible to do it?

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: Tell them to use Chrome.

Comment: no, you cant configure someones browser, you can however alert and tell them the page works best like that, thats all, this sounds like it may be a unethical question...

Answer (score 0):

I would discuss with the client that changing the browser out-of-the-box controls and behavior is not considered as a good practice.
It will be threat as non-reliable site, because it impacts the usability of your site and people will be frustrated and can even report your site and scam